# Accessing the windowing system on Mac

Tags: macos, graphics, quartz-2d

I have exhaustedly searched the web for a way or tutorial or documentation or manual   to use directly the Quartz Compositor, the windowing system for Mac... Here's is what I want: When I program using Qt for example, I create a widget that becomes a window in my app and paints itself etc..., I want to code what that widget does directly. I've been programming. I want to use the lowest level of graphical programming that can be in a computer, no matter how complicated it may be. So I'm beginning with the Quartz compositor because I'm using a Mac. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do that regular Cocoa windows won't let you do? You don't normally go low level just for the fun of it; you go there because the high level abstraction hid something from you. What is it that you're after?

Comment: If you use OpenGL code (via, say, an `NSWindow` containing an `NSOpenGLView`), you will be writing as directly to the hardware as is physically possible. The Quartz Compositor [draws via OpenGL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz_Compositor), as well.

Comment: I'm doing it for two reasons:To harvest the maximum efficiency in terms of graphics I can and for the sake of learning in practice what the low level is like... I think it is possible to go lower than the QuartzGL, because the QuartzGL is compiled right? if I can only find some docs on it :)